# WPF "inherit" storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, resourcedictionary

I have a Storyboard defined in a Resource-XAML (Opacity and Rendertransform). Now I'd like to use it on my different Usercontrols. Since this is a Fade-in animation, it's crucial that the logic of the Usercontrol starts after the animation ends.
So I know about the "Completed" event of a storyboard but I can't see, how to apply here, since I needed to define the Eventhandler on the UserControl consuming the animation. (There are several Usercontrols each with their own actions to perform after being loaded...)

The Styles have a Property called "BasedOn", here I can define the parent... Is there something similar at the Storyboard object too, or do I have to redesign my code?
Anyway if there is a better way for using Standard animations across the project than via Resourcedictionary, please advise me.
Thanks in advance,
Daniel

edit:

here there part of the resdic.

```
   <Storyboard  x:Key="ShowAndGrow">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                     To="1" />
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                     To="1" />
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                     To="1" />
</Storyboard>
```

I apply it in a Usercontrol

```
    <UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowAndGrow}">                
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

an here I needed to add the completed Event somehow....

Comment: In your case is not possible to add your completed event in code- behind instead of the resource-XAML?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a sample of XAML and/or applicable code behind so we can see what you have already? (eg - do you refer to the animations at all in the code behind? Do you use an MVVM approach - ie will the code to be run when the storyboard completes by on the View or in the View Model?)

Comment: When using WPF, it is common to have certain code repeated like in this scenario. However, you *could* store your `Storyboard` in the `Resources` section and programmatically change all of the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` values and the `Completed` event handlers. Of course, if you did that, then you would have to programmatically hook it up to the `Loaded` event of each `UserControl` as well, as that wouldn't work from XAML alone.

Comment: @Core-One: it woulb be possible at all, I just wanted to use the base animation as a template

Comment: @DavidEdey: I'm pretty new in WPF so I can't tell you wether I use any pattern. :) Sure I try to split UI and business logic... :)

Comment: @Sheridan: could you please give me some hints how to achieve this? Gettingthe loaded Event is not the problem, but how to work with templated storyboards?

Comment: What do you mean by *templated storyboards*?

Comment: @Sheridan: defined in Resourcedictionary - sorry for the incorrect terminology :)

Answer (score 0):

So I followed Core-One's and Sheridan's suggestions and added the Storyboard in Codebehind using findresource. I just wonder, if the "correct" way were to define as much as possible in XAML, there is no way to adapt the templated animations...
Thanks guys to all of you!
BR,
Daniel

```
    Private Sub UserControl_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim sb As Storyboard = FindResource("ShowAndGrow")
    AddHandler sb.Completed, AddressOf StartAction
    sb.Begin(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: *I just wonder, if the "correct" way were to define as much as possible in XAML*... that's the way that I use WPF. I gave up trying not to duplicate any code long, long ago, as it's generally just not worth the trouble it causes.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a `Storyboard` from a `Resources` collection using the `Resources` property:

```
Storyboard storyboard = this.Resources["YourStoryboard"] as Storyboard;
```

However, you really need to get access to the `DoubleAnimation` elements, so you'll need to name them too. You'd then be able to reassign the target property like this:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(YourDoubleAnimation, YourUiControl);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(YourDoubleAnimation, 
    new PropertyPath(Control.OpacityProperty));
```

You can find further examples in the [Working with Animations Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189069(VS.95).aspx) page on MSDN (ignore the fact that it is for Silverlight as it will work just the same in WPF).

Comment: thank you, in my case it's really just the Event I had to attach "later". the rest of it is OK as it is :) thank you for the useful link.